# A very basic calculator in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, console, calculator

I'm trying to learn C#, I made this calculator with my current knowledge. It works as I intended, but I'd appreciate some input on my code.

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double input1;
            string input2;
            double input3;

            Console.WriteLine("Super cool calculator 1.0");

            Console.WriteLine("This can perform +, -, / or * with two numbers.");

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter first number:");
                input1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter operator (+, -, /, *)");
                input2 = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter second number:");
                input3 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Calculate(input1, input2, input3);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input! Try again!");
                Main(null);
            }

        }


        static void Calculate(double n1, string n2, double n3)
        {
            string op = n2;
            switch (op)
            {

                case "+":
                    Console.WriteLine($"The answer is {n1} + {n3} = {n1 + n3}");
                    Main(null);
                    break;

                case "-":
                    Console.WriteLine($"The answer is {n1} - {n3} = {n1 - n3}");
                    Main(null);
                    break;

                case "/":
                    Console.WriteLine($"The answer is {n1} / {n3} = {n1 / n3}");
                    Main(null);
                    break;

                case "*":
                    Console.WriteLine($"The answer is {n1} * {n3} = {n1 * n3}");
                    Main(null);
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operation!");
                    Main(null);
                    break;
            }

        }




    }
}
```

Comment: I love your `Main(null)` calls :). Later today I will leave a proper review.

Answer (score 4):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

In C# you can change the `Main` method's signature to [one of the followings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line#overview) depending on your needs:

```
public static void Main() { }
public static int Main() { }
public static void Main(string[] args) { }
public static int Main(string[] args) { }
public static async Task Main() { }
public static async Task<int> Main() { }
public static async Task Main(string[] args) { }
public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args) { }
```

So, you don't need to use the `string[] args` version.

---

```
double input1;
string input2;
double input3;
```

Try to express your intent with the variable names. I would suggest the following renamings:

- `input1` >> `lhsOperand`
- `input3` >> `rhsOperand`
- `input2` >> `infixOperator`

---

```
try
{
     ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input! Try again!");
     Main(null);
}
```

I would suggest to try to avoid recursion if you are a beginner in C#. Please prefer [do-while loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-do-statement) instead. With that structure you can express your code like this *"please provide input data until all are considered valid"*.

---

```
input1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Please prefer [`double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-7.0) which is a [tester-doer pattern](https://thedeveloperblog.com/tester-doer).

- If the input can be parsed as double then the method will return `true` and will populate the second parameter with the parsed value.
- If it can't parse the input then the method will return `false` and will populate the second parameter with default value (`0`).

---

```
default:
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Operation!");
    Main(null);
    break;
```

I would suggest to perform the operator validity check inside the `Main` method. `Main` should request input data and validate them. It should call `Calculate` only if all the input data are considered valid.

---

```
void Calculate(double n1, string n2, double n3)
```

Please use more expressive parameter names than these.

---

```
string op = n2;
```

This line of code is unnecessary, you can do the branching against the method parameter.

---

```
case "+":
    Console.WriteLine($"The answer is {n1} + {n3} = {n1 + n3}");
    Main(null);
    break;
```

In all of your branches you are repeating yourself:

- Write out the result of the calculation
- Re-execute the program

The only difference is the printed text. So, I would suggest to change the return type of `Calculate` to `double` and do the following:

```
static double Calculate(double lhsOperand, string infixOperator, double rhsOperand)
{
    switch (infixOperator)
    {
        case "+": return lhsOperand + rhsOperand;
        case "-": return lhsOperand - rhsOperand;
        case "/": return lhsOperand / rhsOperand;
        case "*": return lhsOperand * rhsOperand;
        default: return double.NaN; //or replace it with anything appropriate
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
Console.WriteLine($"The answer for {lhsOperand} {infixOperator} {rhsOperand} is {Calculate(lhsOperand, infixOperator, rhsOperand)}");
```

Or a super-concise version could be:

```
var result = infixOperator switch
{
    "+" => lhsOperand + rhsOperand,
    "-" => lhsOperand - rhsOperand,
    "/" => lhsOperand / rhsOperand,
    "*" => lhsOperand * rhsOperand,
    _ => double.NaN,
};
Console.WriteLine($"The answer is {lhsOperand} {infixOperator} {rhsOperand} = {result}");
```

which would eliminate the need for the `Calculate` function entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed review :)

Comment: I would avoid this recursion as a non-beginner as well to be honest

Comment: @harold Yes, you are right :)

Comment: @PeterCsala I disagree with the use of `double.TryParse` the value is set to 0 if it fails... How would you check if the client passed in 0 or was it the TryParse that set it to 0? I think the `try-catch-finally` approach here is totally fine.

Comment: @I_throw_but_dont_catch If the app user provides 0 then the TryParse returns true. If the app user provides zero as a string then the TryParse returns false. So, you can distinguish 0 as a valid input from malformed inputs.